# Getting "Server refused our key" from PuTTY when doing gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, putty, google-cloud-shell

Trying to connect to my Google Cloud Shell instance from localhost.

Have done:

```
  gcloud components update
  gcloud auth login
```

Both run successfully.

Then I try:

```
  gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh
```

After a few moments I get a popup saying "No supported authentication methods available." Behind that popup is the PuTTY screen saying "Using username [my@email]" and "Server refused our key."

I cleared out all the files from c:\users[me].ssh and tried again -- same error.

I have confirmed that I can access cloud shell for this account from the web-based Cloud Console.

Any help/ideas appreciated...

-Michael

Comment: This type of question is more suited to Serverfault where it should be asked. Stackoverflow is generally for developers and Serverfault is aimed at system and network administrators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an engineer working on Cloud Shell. This is a known issue with the `cloud-shell` command group in gcloud. We're expecting to have a fix rolled out in the next day or two. I'll update here when we do - in the meantime you'll have to use the web-based console.

Thanks for helping us sort out the bugs in the alpha :)

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the update. This is going to be killer functionality when you get it rolling. Would there be anything in the mechanism preventing me from doing a remote X session over an SSH tunnel from my local machine --> Cloud Shell --> a Linux server on GCE?

Comment: The fix should now be rolled out and you should be able to connect from gcloud again. I don't think there's anything that should prevent using Cloud Shell as an SSH tunnel, though note that there are some restrictions on ports for outgoing connections: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations. Also, if you're installing custom software on Cloud Shell, you might be interested in another alpha feature we're working on that allows you to permanently cusotmize you environment. Email cloud-shell-custom-environments-alpha@googlegroups.com if you're interested in being whitelisted for this.